# Remove all trailing white space with powershell in batch file?

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, whitespace

This works to remove one white space from the ends of all lines in all txt files next to the batch file this runs in:

```
start /wait /min Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem '*.txt' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace ' $', '' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

Is there a way to modify the above so it removes *any* amount of white space (including tabs) from the ends of lines?

I just want to safeguard against there being two or more spaces and/or tabs at the ends of lines.

I have been looking all morning and trying different variations on the above, to no avail.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the regex to replace any number of blanks.

Instead of using the regex  `$`, use  `+$`, so the clause becomes `-replace ' +$'`.

The `+` means : "one or more repetitions".

Comment: I knew it had to be something this simple but I'm almost a total beginner at this stuff, cheers.